# Short story about an astronaut who discovers an injured alien

Tags: story-identification, aliens, short-stories

I am trying to find a book of short science fiction stories that contains a short story about an astronaut crew that land on a moon or planet and one astronaut on an EVA (spacewalk) on the surface discovers a crew of three aliens next to a crashed ship. One of them injured. He sends them back to his ship sacrificing his spot aboard for them. I believe the story is called "The Samaritan".

Comment: If you know the title, look it up on [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/). There are 15 results for fiction titles containing `Samaritan`.

Comment: Oh my god! I have been search for this for over 2 and a half decades! I first read the short story in an anthology of american literature when I was in grade school in Jamaica! Been searching for it ever since. Thank you! This is so divine

Comment: That is correct. The book I am looking for was an American literature book and it also had: Survivor, by Walter F. Moudy
Expendable, by Philip Dick

Answer (score 14):

It sounds like *The Samaritan* by Richard Harper. The short story originally appeared in the Feb. 1963 issue of *Boys' Life*, but has appeared in several subsequent anthologies. A bibiography is available on [isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?96006).